# No slider in Google Maps zoom control

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, controls, zooming

I read in google.maps docs :

> google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE - displays the standard zoom slider control

Creating google map I set `zoomControlOptions.style` as `ZoomControlStyle.LARGE`:

```
this_m_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this_m_div_map), { 
    zoom: this_m_zoomLevel,
    panControl : true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
    },

    zoomControl : true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
    },

    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    },

    center: new google.maps.LatLng(this_m_defaultLocationLat, this_m_defaultLocationLng),
    //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    //styles: selectedStyle
});
```

But I still see no sliders on my map:
http://s020.radikal.ru/i714/1508/fe/74fbd1abdeeb.png

What is wong? Can any other options influence slider?

Answer (score 0):

The map obviously is a **signed-in** map, the zoom-control isn't configurable in such a map, see:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin#changes_to_map_controls

The only option you have is to use not a **signed-in**-map (remove the `signed_in`-parameter from the API-URL)